# Microsoft Project - View Resource Cost for a Specific Timeframe

Tags: ms-project, cost-management

Using Microsoft Project 2010, how do I view how much a resource costs the project between a specific time period?

For example, I want to view how much the "HR" resource cost the project between September 13th, 2012 and November 15th, 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been talking to someone who has used MS project for a while now, as far as he knows this is not possible to do. He suggested I print out the total for each week and add them up manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the costs or custom reports in project 2010 and get reports based on your requirements.